# struct inotify_event *event=(struct inotify_event*)&buffer[i]

Tags: c, linux, events, inotify

I am working on a project called monitoring system using `inotify` I saw some sample code online but I didn't understand this line. `inotify_event` makes you notified about the event/changes in file/directory. But what `*event` does and why is &buffer[i] used? Could you please explain it to me?
Here is the link to the sample code: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/

```
struct inotify_event *event=(struct inotify_event*)&buffer[i];
```

Comment: Read `man inotify`

Comment: `struct inotify_event *event=(struct inotify_event*)&buffer[i];` is a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  You can't safely treat an array of `char` values as something it's not.  The code in that link also ignores the possibility of a short read.

Comment: `struct inotify_event` is a data type used by inotify.  `struct inotify_event *event` declares `event` as a pointer to an object of type `struct inotify_event`.  As it appears in that declaration, `=(struct inotify_event*)&buffer[i]` is an *initializer*, specifying the initial value of `event` to be a pointer to the address of the `i`th element of array `buffer`.  This may or may not constitute a strict-aliasing violation, depending on the element type of `buffer`, among other details.